# How to customize the cell views and make them scroll horizontally programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to establish a view that I saw in an app. The user get to select an image and can apply filter on the images. The problem is my size for cells are not correct and my collection view would not scroll horizontally.

**This is what I expected:**
[image]

**This is what I got so far with the code provided below:**
[image]

```swift
extension SHViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! SHCollectionViewCell
        var filteredImage = smallImage
        if indexPath.row != 0 {
            filteredImage = createFilteredImage(filterName: filterNameList[indexPath.row], image: smallImage)
        }

        cell.imageView.image = filteredImage
        cell.filterNameLabel.text = filterDisplayNameList[indexPath.row]
        updateCellFont()
        return cell
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filterNameList.count
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        filterIndex = indexPath.row
        if filterIndex != 0 {
            applyFilter()
        } else {
            imageView.image = image
        }
        updateCellFont()
        scrollCollectionViewToIndex(itemIndex: indexPath.item)
    }

    func updateCellFont() {
        // update font of selected cell
        if let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: filterIndex, section: 0)) {
            let cell = selectedCell as! SHCollectionViewCell
            cell.filterNameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        }

        for i in 0...filterNameList.count - 1 {
            if i != filterIndex {
                // update nonselected cell font
                if let unselectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) {
                    let cell = unselectedCell as! SHCollectionViewCell
                    if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
                        cell.filterNameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.thin)
                    } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                        cell.filterNameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func scrollCollectionViewToIndex(itemIndex: Int) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: itemIndex, section: 0)
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }

}
```

```swift
    class SHCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let filterNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        return label
    }()

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        return iv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        [filterNameLabel, imageView].forEach { addSubview($0) }

        filterNameLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor)
        imageView.anchor(top: filterNameLabel.bottomAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and **return the required cell size** like this

```
extension SHViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/4, height: collectionView.frame.height)

}
```